# jQuery get data as object or array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I would like to get all elements with class `.my-data-tid` and `data-tid` values into an object or array

```
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="1">1</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="2">2</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="3">3</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="4">4</div>
```

with

```
var tid = $('.my-data-tid').data('tid');
```

I get only the first value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to convert jquery selector object to object contain target values and use [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to convert result to array.

```js
var tid = $('.my-data-tid').map(function(){
  return $(this).data('tid');
}).toArray();
console.log(tid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="1">1</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="2">2</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="3">3</div>
<div class="my-data-tid" data-tid="4">4</div>
```